# mysql table design, large column size vs large number of rows

Tags: mysql

Please help me understand which of the following is better for scaling and performance.

```
Table: test
columns: id <int, primary key>, doc <int>, keyword <string>
```

The data i want to store is a pointer to the documents containing a particular keyword

Design 1:

```
have unique constraint on the keyword column and store the list of documents as an array
e.g id: 1, doc: [4,5,6], keyword: google
```

Design 2:

```
insert a row for each document  
1 4 google  
2 5 google  
3 6 google
```

Lets the say the average number of documents a particular keyword would be found in is close to 100000. there may not be a max number of documents the keyword appears in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forget about option 1 because there's no array data type in mysql.

To be honest if you want a scallable solution for this type of data I think you should look into a different type of database. Research more on NoSQL and 'key-value pair store database'.

With mysql, the best I can think of is your 2nd option, with the exception that you should create another table with a numeric ID and a list of unique keywords. That way, when you do your search you'll first look up the ID, then filter the big table by the ID instead of string. Numeric comparison is faster than string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of factors come into scaling and performance so it's not usually a good idea to try to optimise unknowns early in development.

For database design I find it's usually best to go with the more correct normalised approach (your design 2) and then worry about the scaling and performance if it becomes an issue. You can then de-normalise certain areas or take other approaches depending on what issues you face.

Your design option 1 is likely to hit other issues more immediately with the inability to join the doc column with another table, as well as complexities updating and searching it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Design 1 is potentially limited by [MySQL's row size limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

Design 2 makes the most sense to me. What if you need to remove one of those values? You just delete a row rather than having to search through and update an array. It's also nice because it allows you to limit the size of your results if necessary (e.g., for pagination).

You might also consider creating a many-to-many relationship between this table and a **keywords** table instead of storing keywords as a field here.